# PHP Facebook SDK - Send invites to facebook friends about your application

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm a bit confused with all the different versions of developer SDKs Facebook provided over the years.

I would like to know as of now (Sept 2017), if its possible for a PHP application to use Facebook's SDK to let a user send invites to his Facebook friends.

More specifically, more or less, the following workflow:

1. User clicks a button 'Invite friends from Facebook'.
2. Popup form let him login with his Facebook credentials.
3. Message box and a list of all his friends appears, allowing him to type a message and select one or more friends.
4. By pressing submit all his selected friends should receive a Facebook notification from him with the message specified.

Comment: This has rather little to do with what SDK you are using. What type of app it is, is important. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#faq_104376946653191, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#faq_1291953124230220

Comment: Thanks for the reference! So the closest thing to what I am trying to do, is the `Send Dialog` which only appears to be available in Javascript SDK?

Comment: I can see no backend alternative with the current version of their SDK..

Comment: Yeah, but you can use them both, they are made to work hand-in-hand, so to speak ...